# Why does the md5 algorithm accept numpy's int64 but not integers when hashing?

Tags: python, numpy, hash, md5

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.md5
```

I am currently trying to understand why the following line works:

```
hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()
```

And this line doesn't:

```
hash(identifier).digest()
```

This second line basically shows the following error: `object supporting the buffer API required`

As a side note, the `identifier` variable is an integer. As far as I know, integers (the default integer in Python) occupies 32 bits (or 4 bytes) and numpy's np.int64 occupies 64 bits (or 8 bytes) of memory.

Then, why does the first line work and the second doesn't? Is that a requirement of md5?

Comment: "As far as I know, integers (the default integer in Python) occupies 32 bits (or 4 bytes)" No, they are not. Python `int` objects are, well, objects, like everything in Python, and their underlying representation is arbitrary sized, so your integers can be as big as you want as long as you have memory (and address space...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works because numpy integers were nice enough to implement the so called [Buffer API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html). hashlib.md5 expects a bytes-like object. A python int is not a bytes-like object. An object that implements the Buffer API can be translated into a bytes-like object. It has nothing to do with the MD5 algorithm in general.